# Running unit test from an open-wc/lit project doesn't hit breakpoints

Tags: node.js, debugging, testing

I have a typescript project, which was setup with open-wc scaffolding (npm init @open-wc).
I wrote a few unit tests, set breakpoints in the code, but those were not hit. Also the 'debugger' statement doesn't break.

Any ideas?

Steps to reproduce (nodejs must be installed for this):

1. Start Visual Studio Code
2. Run `npm init @open-wc`
3. Choose 'Scaffold a new project`, 'Application', Select 'Testing', Select 'Yes' for typescript, Choose a tag name, and select write to disk.
4. Choose npm.
5. Open `demo-tag.test.js` and set a breakpoint in a test.
6. Open `package.json`
7. Hover above the line `"test": "tsc && wtr --coverage"`. When the tooltip appears, choose `Debug Script`.

Now the test is in debug mode, but the breakpoint was not hit. Also, if you set a breakpoint in the compile `.js` code, it will not work.